# trying to make a template driven form with preset values

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a template driven form with preset values
all was going fine until I added 'ng Model', it clears the values

```
        <div >
            <div *ngFor="let opinion of content.opinions">
                <label>شخص1 </label>
                <input ngModel  [value]="opinion.name" type="text" placeholder="اسم"
                    name="name" />
                <input  ngModel [value]="opinion.prof" type="text"
                    placeholder="تخصص" name="prof" />
                <textarea ngModel [value]="opinion.comment" type="text"
                    placeholder="رأي" name="comment"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: [(ngModel)] gives you input and output both binding. you can simply use `[(ngModel)]="model.name"` and `[(ngModel)]="model. prof"` like this.

Comment: this does not work with 'ng for' as it give all the fields the same value

Comment: here is more explanation I think the problem is not with ng for but with using <form>
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xexxsh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code to resolve the issue faced by you. While using ngFor in the forms you need to identify the inputs uniquely by specifying the name uniquely. So You can use the index of the for loop or else you can add id in your object and use that as the value of **name** attribute. I have written the code using the index.

if you want to bind the variable with input as well as want to save the changes in input to the variable directly you can simply update your code to the following:

```
 <div *ngFor="let opinion of content.opinions;let i=index" class="control-panel__opinions-person">
                <label>شخص1 </label>
                <input class="control-panel__opinions-name" type="text" placeholder="اسم" [(ngModel)]='opinion.name'
                    name="name{{i}}" />
                <input class="control-panel__opinions-prof" [(ngModel)]='opinion.prof' type="text"
                    placeholder="تخصص" name="prof{{i}}" />
                <textarea class="control-panel__opinions-comment" type="text" placeholder="رأي" name="comment{{i}}"
                    [(ngModel)]='opinion.comment'></textarea>
            </div>
```

If you want to have the input as that of preset value and want to add some other logic for the output, than you can use two different ways for input as well as output.
For reference I am just changing the value of the variable when user changes the field value. Please refer the following code:

```
 <div >
        <div *ngFor="let opinion of content.opinions; let i=index">
            <label>شخص1 </label>
            <input #name [ngModel]="opinion.name" (ngModelChange)="opinion.name=name.value" type="text" placeholder="اسم"
                name="name{{i}}" />
            <input  #prof ngModel [ngModel]="opinion.prof" (ngModelChange)="opinion.prof=prof.value" type="text"
                placeholder="تخصص" name="prof{{i}}" />
            <textarea #comment [ngModel]="opinion.comment" (ngModelChange)="opinion.comment=comment.value" type="text"
                placeholder="رأي" name="comment{{i}}"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: with `ng for` all fields take the same value

Comment: here is more explanation I think the problem is not with ng for but with using <form>
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xexxsh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I have updated the above solution. I hope you find it useful.